# How can I commit another change while the change is already being added to the stage?

Tags: git

Thank you browse this question.

I am making a script to automatically commit changes.

Is there a way to commit only the specified lines in the specified file when some changes have already been added to the stage?

for instance,

I have a blank hoge.txt.

Then, I add some lines and commit them.

```
diff --git a/hoge.txt b/hoge.txt
index e69de29..b3c5a95 100644
--- a/hoge.txt
+++ b/hoge.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,5 @@
+line1
+line2
+line3
+line4
+line5
```

`git status` says:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   hoge.txt
```

Then, I add some lines more line0 and line6.

```
diff --git a/hoge.txt b/hoge.txt
index b3c5a95..6006aa3 100644
--- a/hoge.txt
+++ b/hoge.txt
@@ -1,5 +1,7 @@
+line0
 line1
 line2
 line3
 line4
 line5
+line6
```

`git status` says:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   hoge.txt

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   hoge.txt
```

Now, I wanna commit only changes not staged without changes staged. But, lines 1 to 5 must be staged.

`git status` says:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   hoge.txt
```

`git diff --cached` says:

```
diff --git a/hoge.txt b/hoge.txt
index 588aa45..6006aa3 100644
--- a/hoge.txt
+++ b/hoge.txt
@@ -1,2 +1,7 @@
 line0
+line1
+line2
+line3
+line4
+line5
 line6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't...

The goal of the "stage" zone is to contain all the files you need for your next commit, so you can't make a commit from unstaged files ignoring the staged one.

Although you want to do something weird, what you can do is :

1. Stash your 1st change : `git stash`
2. Make your 2nd change
3. Add it to your stage zone : `git add hoge.txt`
4. Commit your work : `git commit -m 'myWork'`
5. Get back your 1st change : `git stash pop`

You will get a conflict to resolve but you're going to commit your 2nd change before your 1st one.